How to hatch and color the colored region/the interior of a contour but not the white region/the exterior
I want to superpose red blue green and black contours but coloring and hatching the interior of the contours with the exterior of the contour staying empty instead of being white.
My contours
All I have found is this where they manually build a colormap with an alpha set to zero for the white values but it seems a bit complicated.
Does anyone know a simpler way to do what I want (for example if contour have a "fill" functionality or if contourf can have a varying alpha for the different regions)?

Please limit yout question to a specific problem. Are you asking how to fetch the different contours? Are you asking how to hatch fill them? Please give a sketch of the expected outcome and share some code that shows what you tried and where you got stuck.
